# Improved Iterative Scaling Method when # feature is large

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning

In log-linear model, we can find maximum entropy solution using IIS.
We update the parameters by finding a paramters which makes model expectation over a feature and empirical expectation matches.
However, there is a exp( sum of all features) in the equation.
My question is that when the number of feature is large (say 10000) then summation over all the features will blow easily. How can we solve this problem by numerical method ? To me it seems impossible since even compute exp(50) will blow.

Comment: May the logarithm be with you.

Comment: Summation over logarithm can not be computed

Answer (score 3):

Do computations in log-space, and use a `logsumexp` operation (borrowed from [scikit-learn](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L223)):

```
// Pseudocode for 1-d version of logsumexp:
// computes log(sum(exp(x) for x in a)) in a numerically stable way.
def logsumexp(a : array of float):
    amax = maximum(a)
    sum = 0.
    for x in a:
        sum += exp(x - amax)
    return log(sum) + amax
```

This summation can be done once, before the start of the main loop, because the feature values don't change while you're optimizing.

Side remark: IIS is quite old-fashioned. [Since some 10 years](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/W/W02/W02-2018.pdf), almost everyone's been using L-BFGS-B, OWL-QN or (A)SGD to fit log-linear models.

Comment: thank you, however, my problem has exponentially many configuration to sum, so I can't explicitly sum them up, need to approximate. I can't use other optimization algorithm like LFBGS since I don't have exact gradient direction.

Comment: @Jing: I seem to misunderstand your question. Are you worried about efficiency, or numerical stability?

Comment: Say, the summation over feature fsum is something like 10000
doesn't that mean each update we only get tiny of gradient ? since those "gradient" parameter is coupled with fsum in the exponential function

Comment: @Jing: As for efficiency, note that the values don't change inside the loop, so you only need to run logsumexp once. I don't understand your second remark.

Comment: Since, I have exponentially many configuration to sum up, so I can't just sum them up. So I can not compute the gradient of (empirical expectation = model expectation) exactly.

Comment: Hi, are you answering this "the summation over feature fsum is something like 10000 doesn't that mean each update we only get tiny of gradient ?"

I am a bit confused. ~"~

Comment: @Jing What kind of crazy model are you fitting?

Comment: Aren't those typically fit with Gibbs sampling instead of IIS?

Comment: yeah, but I hust wanna try if IIS, GIS achieves better convergence. since IIS did converge faster than, say gradient ascent in MaxEnt.